# Orthogonal decomposition of a symmetrical bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Be $n\ge2$, I have to find a orthogonal decomposition $V=V_+\oplus V_-\oplus V_0$ with sylvester's law of inertia of

[image]

which is a symmetrical bilinear form $b_A$ of $V=\mathbb{R}^n$.
And I also have to find the signature of $A$.

But I just don't even understand what to do here, for the orthogonal decomposition I guess I have to find the eigenvalues of A which are $3$ and$-1$, so is the solution just a zero matrix with 3 ones and then -1's on the diagonal?

I feel kinda lost here any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the idea. There are two eigenvalues, namely $n-1$ (with multiplicity $1$; here $n$ is the dimension of $A$) and $-1$ (with multiplicity $n-1$). The $(n-1)$-eigenspace is spanned by the eigenvector $(1,\ldots,1)$, and the $(-1)$-eigenspace is spanned by the $n-1$ eigenvectors of the form $(-1,0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$. The signature of $A$ is therefore $(1,n-1,0)$.